# MongoDB aggregate array

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Say I have a MongoDB collection with documents like—

```
{
  "name": "Hawaiian",
  "toppings": ['cheese', 'ham', 'pineapple'],
}
```

How could I get a list of all the collection's `toppings`?

I assume I'd have to use MapReduce or the new aggregation framework (ideally MapReduce as I can't use the new aggregation framework), but I'm not sure how to do it.

Thanks!

**Edit**: And, is there a way to count the number of distinct toppings at the database level?

Comment: Are you trying to just iterate through the toppings array?  `$cursor = $collection->find(toppings);
$array = iterator_to_array($cursor);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB supports [DISTINCT](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Distinct) aggregation. This should do the trick.

Comment: On a related note—do you know how I can count that at the database layer (not calling `len` on the returned list)?

Comment: `db.collection.distinct('toppings').length` returns the length. This is in mongodb console. Doesn't look like pymongo has that built-in.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`distinct`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.distinct) query for that:

```
db.coll.distinct('toppings')
```

Answer (score 1):

distinct will work for a limited number of unique items (<=50k?)

### if more than that you got to use mapreduce

fun_map ="""function ()  for (e in this.toppings) { emit  (entities.toppings[e],1); } """

fun_reduce = """function (key, values) {var total = 0; for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { total += values[i]; } return total;}""" 
then you call

### collection.map_reduce(fun_map,fun_reduce,out={"replace":'your_outputcollection_name"},  full_response=True)

your topings items will be the _id of your output collection while value will represent a count of each particula toping